# JSF Compound Rendered Attribute Not Working

Tags: jsf, attributes

I'm trying to modify a condition in a rendered attribute but for some reason it doesn't want to cooperate, and unfortunately I'm not entirely familiar with EL.

When I try the code like this, it works, and the element is rendered or not appropriately:

```
rendered = "#{!(bean.boolOne) or (bean.boolTwo)}"
```

But when I try it like this, the page I'm trying to view doesn't even show

```
rendered = "#{!(bean.boolOne) or (bean.boolOne and bean.boolTwo)}"
```

I didn't think I changed that much to make it break, but if anyone could provide some insight I'd be grateful!

Comment: looks fine to me, have you tried debugging what values are you getting, perhaps you have `bean.boolOne=true` and `bean.boolTwo=false` which will not render for second so it might be working but you couldnt see it.

Comment: Does the EL not evaluate to the boolean result you're expecting or does it actually break your entire page as in, white screen/exception stacktrace?

Comment: So I must have been making some stupid syntax error in the xhtml document. It wasn't going to a stack trace, just didn't load any page with that particular piece of code on it. But, I went back and looked at it again this morning and everything seems to be working well.  Sorry to waste everyone's time!